# How to set dropdown value in angular 7

Tags: angular6, angular7, angular8

I am trying to set dropdown value by programmatically using formcontrolname but not working.I have given my code below.How to set dropdown value that?Anyone can have idea?please help to find the solution.

app.component.html:

```
<p-dropdown [values]="dropdownData" fornControlName="datavalue"><p-dropdown>
```

app.component.ts:

```
dropdownData=[
{name:'UK',value:'UK'},
{name:'USA',value:'USA'},
{name:'CHINAA',value:'CHINAA'}
];

this.myform=this.fb.group({

datavalue:[null]

});

ngOnInit(){

this.myform.controls['datavalue'].setValue("USA");

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could work if you changed `setValue` as follows.

```
this.myform.controls['datavalue'].setValue(dropdownData[0]);
```

You should however inverse the logic and address the model from within your template using `ngModel`.

***app.component.html:***

```
<p-dropdown [values]="dropdownData" [(ngModel)]="selectedData"><p-dropdown>
```

***app.component.ts:***

```
dropdownData = [
    {name:'UK',value:'UK'},
    {name:'USA',value:'USA'},
    {name:'CHINAA',value:'CHINAA'}
];
selectedData = dropdownData[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Please set the value like below in your app.component.ts:

```
this.myform.controls['datavalue'].setValue("USA", { onlySelf: true });
```

Also, please change the code in app.component.html like below:-

```
<p-dropdown [options]="dropdownData" fornControlName="datavalue"><p-dropdown>
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: How to set checkbox like checked condition on programmatically?

Comment: Could you please share the code where you are trying to check the checkbox dynamically.